# Getting error number 3464 data type mismatch in ms access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm not sure if it is because of problems in the below SQL coding which gives me both the Error 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression, and runtime error 91 object variable or With block variable not yet. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
SQL = "SELECT TempRFQ.[RFQID] AS [RFQID], TempRFQ.[LI] AS [LI], TempRFQ.[QTY] AS [QTY], TempRFQ.[UI] AS [UI], TempRFQ.[PN] AS [PN], " & _
"TempRFQ.[Description] AS [Description], TempRFQ.MFR AS [MFR], TempRFQ.MFC AS [MFC], TempRFQ.[AC] AS [AC], TempRFQ.[Remarks] AS [Remarks] " & _
"FROM RFQ INNER JOIN TempRFQ ON RFQ.[RFQID] = TempRFQ.[RFQID] " & _
"WHERE RFQ.[RFQID] ='" & Me![RFQID] & "' ORDER BY len(TempRFQ.[LI]),TempRFQ.[LI];"
```

Comment: Try `"WHERE RFQ.[RFQID] =" & Me![RFQID] & " ORDER BY len(TempRFQ.[LI]),TempRFQ.[LI];"` - removing the single quotes from around `Me![RFQID]` if it's a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks that's it. It is that simple. Thanks for the help!